# Safari can’t establish a secure connection to the server

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, safari, https, ident.ca

I realize there is another question with the same title, but my situation is very different.

- The problem started on three of my computers after upgrading from Leopard to Snow Leopard.
- I can login to gmail and facebook using https with no problem.
- I can not login to https://identi.ca/main/login or https://seminars.wolfram.com/ or https://panopticlick.eff.org with Safari, works fine with Firefox.
- Already tried "Safari Reset..."

Any ideas?

Comment: Using Firefox, I have just discovered that both problematic sites use certificates issued by Comodo

Comment: Related: [Why won't OS X trust GitHub's SSL certificate?](http://superuser.com/questions/605900/why-wont-os-x-trust-githubs-ssl-certificate) and [HTTPS certificates invalid on Safari, Chrome on specific user account](http://superuser.com/questions/788082/https-certificates-invalid-on-safari-chrome-on-specific-user-account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved this problem by following this procedure published by phurd99 in the Apple Support Forums:

1. Open applications
2. Utiliities
3. Open Keychain
4. Click Keychain Access and select Preferences.
5. Click the "Reset My Default Keychain"

(...)

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2138178&start=15&tstart=0

This solves the problem but you are left without you precious keychain (a backup is saved).

Then, using the backup and trial and error I discovered that by deleting one specific certificate, the problem is solved:

UNT-USERFirst-Hardware
Intermediate certificate authority
Note: This certificate is signed by an untrusted issuer

Comment: [+1] Searching for UNT-USERFirst-Hardware revealed 2 such certificates on my machine. One indeed was noted as signed by an untrusted issuer. So I just deleted this certificate and my HTTPS problems with Safari were gone! I couldn't use MobileMe on my MBA because of this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. Adding new root authority certificates from Thawte fixed the problem. Apple has documentation on how to do this here [http://docs.info.apple.com/article.h...en/mh2046.html](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh2046.html)

I added the root and server certificates that I downloaded from here
http://www.thawte.com/roots

Comment: Thanks. Did you have to go through all the 8 directories and 14 subrectories double clicking on every .cer and .pem file? Did you add them to your login keychain or to the system keychain?

Comment: There are dozens of certificates in that download. Which one do I need?